# Drawing a circle on mapkit

Tags: iphone, mapkit, geometry

I got to draw a circle on my map, it has to be about 1,8 miles centered on a point.. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to do 2 steps:

1. Create MKCircle object using `circleWithCenterCoordinate:radius:` method and add it to your mapView (using `addOverlay:` method)
2. In mapView delegate implement `mapView:viewForOverlay:` method, create and setup `MKCircleView` instance there and return it

If you have different overlay types you may need to perform some type-checks in delegate method to create overlay views appropriate for each type of overlay.