# Show circle around selected location

Tags: ios, ios5, mkmapview, mkannotation, cllocation

As we have seen there is a circle around current location in iOS mkmapview. Is there any way to draw a similar circle in mkmapview for location other then current location?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369073/circle-around-a-point-on-an-mkmapview

Maybe it's what you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentations for MKCircle: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKCircle_class/Reference/Reference.html and MKCircleView: http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKCircleView_class/Reference/Reference.html 
 both of which are part of the MapKit API,
you'll find tools for drawing circles! 
As mentioned at this link [Circle around a point on an MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369073/circle-around-a-point-on-an-mkmapview)
there are no easy way to create animations for these circles, however the advantage is that they will provide you with a degree of accuracy for your coordinates on your map!
The steps to creating the circles, one way, is here: [Drawing a circle on mapkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563093/drawing-a-circle-on-mapkit)
Basically, create an MKCircle object using circleWithCenterCoordinate:radius: method and add it to your mapView (using addOverlay: method)
Next, in the mapView delegate, implement mapView:viewForOverlay: method, create and setup MKCircleView instance there and return it.